# Using perl for incrementing numbers in text file

Tags: regex, windows, perl, numbers, text-files

I want to batch-process text files from the command line by adding a static offset to all numbers contained in said files using perl.

For example, if the file contained the line: `AN_IDENTIFIER_TOKEN = 1,` and the offset is `19` then this line should be transformed to `AN_IDENTIFIER_TOKEN = 20,`

I tried to use `perl -pe 's/(\d+)$/19+$1/e' file1.txt` but that did produce the same output as input (no numbers were changed). What is the correct command to pass to perl?

Using ActiveState Perl 5.24.1 on Windows.

Comment: @MukeshIngham: Why do you think so?

Comment: Are the commas `,` that you show really in the data?

Comment: `perl -pe "s/(\s*=\s*)(\d+)$/$1.($2+19)/egs" file1.txt`

Comment: @MukeshIngham: No, I don't trust you. The `/e` modifier allows you to specify an *expression* for the replacement string.

Comment: @Borodin the commas really are in the data.

Comment: @MukeshIngham: You are completely wrong about the power of regexes (particularly their Perl implementation). Using `/e`, then this problem becomes trivial.

Comment: On Windows, you typically need to use double quotes in command-line arguments, i.e. `perl -pe "s/(\d+)$/19+$1/e" file1.txt`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should work, try this:

```
perl -pe "s/(\d+)/19+$1/eg" file1.txt
```

Your regex `(\d+)$` matched only digits at the end of a string, so that won't match `1,`

If you want to match only `" = <digits>,"`, then use something like this

```
perl -pe "s/ = (\d+),/' = '.(19+$1).','/eg" file1.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, that's working perfectly! Could you include a (very brief) explanation of what the `g` and `s` switches do?

Comment: I removed `s`, it's not needed, but `g` means replace all occurrences in each line. Without `g` only the first occurrence will be replaced

Comment: Are you sure the OP wants *all* numbers in a line to be altered? I know that's what they said, but it seems unlikely that the `$` was added accidentally

Comment: @Borodin I really wanted _all_ numbers to be altered, and yes, the `$` was unfortunately a mistake.

Comment: Not trying to be snarky here, but your question about the /g and /e modifiers is answered quite thoroughly in the documentation.   If you are not already familiar with it, do yourself a favor and learn about perldoc.  In this case, you want to read through the perlre docs.  Type 'perldoc perlre' at the command line.  You can learn a LOT about perl from perldoc!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to alter numbers at the *ends* of the lines in the file, and those numbers are always followed by commas, then you can use tnis

```
S/(\d+)(?=,\s*$)/$1+19/e
```

It uses a look-ahead to check that the number is followed by a comma, optional white space, and the end of the line